# Arg parse inside with Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, args

I would need to insert variables for the input file in a 'with' function while reading/writing in it. Here is the part of code that I am currently interested in:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My script")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input',help='Input log file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output',help='Desired name for the Excel file',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s','--sheet',help='Desired name of the Excel sheet(Default: Sheet1)',default='Sheet1',required=False)
args=parser.parse_args()

with open('%s',%args.input, 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace('destination', 'destination          xxx')
with open('%s',%args.input, 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```

`'%s',%args.input, 'r'` is not valid, but I would need something that does this thing. The same for 'w'. Any ways for a workaround?

Many thanks,

Romain

Comment: You could just replace `'%s',%args.input` with `args.input`.

Comment: @c3st7n: Thanks, I had a comma there and that's why did not worked

Comment: Okay :) I am not sure why you would bother using a format string as you are just literally taking the value of `args.input` and not adding anything to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the error:

```
import argparse

parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description="My script")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input',help='Input log file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output',help='Desired name for the Excel file',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-s','--sheet',help='Desired name of the Excel sheet(Default: Sheet1)',default='Sheet1',required=False)
args=parser.parse_args()

with open('%s' %args.input, 'r') as file :
  filedata = file.read()
filedata = filedata.replace('destination', 'destination          xxx')
with open('%s' %args.input, 'w') as file:
  file.write(filedata)
```